# Automatically insert backslash to parse json string with double quotes

Tags: python, json

The following is a example json string which needs to be parsed-

```
'{ 
"name":"bla",
"quote":"bla bla "blah blah" bla",
"occupation":"blabla"
}'
```

I need to insert automatically `\\`  escape the two quotes to parse. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25935332/4048006). But the problem is, it splits the string by `:`, because it assumes that the json string has only one key value. Moreover, i also can not split by `,` because the `quote` section can contain `,` in its text. for example `"quote":"bla bla, "blah blah" bla"`. So, in contrast to that answer, i need a more robust solution. How can I do this? I can not think of any modification of that answer, that will work perfectly in my case.

Comment: This can't be solved in any general, reliable way. Fix whatever application is generating the bogus JSON in the first place so it creates valid JSON.

Comment: The whole reason that JSON requires embedded quotes to be escaped is because anything else is ambiguous. If it could be fixed up automatically, the standard JSON parsers would be able to do it themselves.

Comment: Is the file newlined as your example shows?

Comment: If not, can you supply a few examples formatted exactly as supplied?

Comment: no, that's not new lined. I formated it just to save your time.

Comment: @MainulQuraishi is `:` valid in the body as well? what about `{` or `}`? it would help a lot to post some actual examples rather than a single, doctored example: there is no general malformed JSON fix: any fix will be tailored to the exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a malformed json and there's no robust way of parsing it covering all the possible cases.

If you know that this is the structure of every line, you can try by splitting in a more convoluted way, like with `":"` but this is not reliable. An alternative would be to use a regex but it's more complicated and it may suffer from the same problems.

The best solution would be to go to the person who created this JSON, slap him in the face, and ask him to re-encode the file, but I imagine this is not possible atm.

Comment: Ya, you are right, that's not possible. because those 'quote' key is actually millions of tweets . people often use quote inside their tweets

Comment: And how are you retrieving this data? I don't believe twitter API do not encode properly.

Comment: I am using a crawler. The output the crawler is like this
'{ "name":"bla","quote":"bla bla \"blah blah \" bla","occupation":"blabla"}'
But when i am reading this in my python code, I am getting this-'{ "name":"bla","quote":"bla bla "blah blah " bla","occupation":"blabla"}' . 
That's why, when i tried to replace '\" ' by ' \\" ' ,it's not working. That would have been solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given two (pretty big) premises, it can still be parsed:

1. `{`, `}`, & `:` are not valid values for any of the fields
2. Each entry `{}` has 3 parts

2 could be removed if you generalized the parsing of key/value pairs if the number varies.

1 can also be *slightly* relaxed, if you can say that `:` can **only** appear in the value fields (in any quantity). [This would be mutually exclusive to #2, however.](https://regex101.com/r/8PkSpj/6)

The regex:

```
{\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^:\n\r]*)\",?\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^:\n\r]*)\",?\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^:\n\r]*)\",?}
```

or, as a raw string:

```
r'{"([^"]*)":"([^:\n\r]*)",?"([^"]*)":"([^:\n\r]*)",?"([^"]*)":"([^:\n\r]*)",?}'
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8PkSpj/5)

**NOTE**: This doesn't handle any whitespace in the JSON portions, but that can be added if necessary, it's just pretty long already/

Usage:

```
pattern = r'{"([^"]*)":"([^:\n\r]*)",?"([^"]*)":"([^:\n\r]*)",?"([^"]*)":"([^:\n\r]*)",?}'
matches = re.findall(pattern, input)
for match in matches:
    result = {match[0]: match[1], match[2]: match[3], match[4]: match[5]}
    # Do something with each result
```

In use:

```
>>> pattern = '{\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^:\n\r]*)\",?\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^:\n\r]*)\",?\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^:\n\r]*)\",?}'
>>> matches = re.findall(pattern, input)
>>> for match in matches:
    result = {match[0]: match[1], match[2]: match[3], match[4]: match[5]}
>>> result
{'quote': 'bla bla "blah blah" bla', 'name': 'bla', 'occupation': 'blabla'}
```

Another example:

```
>>> input = """{"name":"b"testst,s'''""'''''''t""e,"la","quote":"bla bla "blah b,lah" bla","occupation":"bl,,,abla"}"""
>>> matches = re.findall(pattern, input)
>>> for match in matches:
        result = {match[0]: match[1], match[2]: match[3], match[4]: match[5]}
>>> result
{'quote': 'bla bla "blah b,lah" bla', 'name': 'b"testst,s\'\'\'""\'\'\'\'\'\'\'t""e,"la', 'occupation': 'bl,,,abla'}
```